# How to stop the automatic data/snapshot process of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am currently using Version 1.0.0 of Apache IoTDB. I found that the size of the "data/snapshot" folder is much larger than that of the "data/sequence" folder. I looked the subfolders of "data/snapshot" and it looks like this is the database snapshot in certain time. However, I don’t seem to have executed relevant commands on snapshots manually, so this seems to be executed automatically. How can I turn off this automatic process of snapshot to save our storage size?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, which has been fixed in Version 1.0.1 of Apache IoTDB. This version has already been released so you can just upgrade to v1.0.1 or the latest v1.1.0 to solve this error.